# context with ko.renderTemplate in custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'd like to use named templates with a custom bindingHandler in knockout, but it seems the viewModel passed into the custom binding is stripped of the context properties of $root, $parent, $component, etc. and in my case I need this context.

When I do ko.renderTemplate on a template that references $parent I get an error - "*ReferenceError: $parent is not defined*"

*NOTE:* binding to the object "bob" is just illustrate I need "bob's" $parent. It seems I can get context for the parent viewModel by doing ko.contextFor(element), but I need the "bob" object's context...

JAVASCRIPT:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

      var templateId = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      console.log(templateId);
            ko.renderTemplate(templateId, viewModel, {}, element, "replaceChildren");
    }
};

var viewModel = function() {
    this.bob = {
       name: ko.observable("bob")
    };
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);
    this.registerClick = function(ctx) {
        console.log(ctx);
        this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

HTML

```
<div>You've clicked <span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks'>&nbsp;</span> times</div>
<div data-bind="with:bob">
    <span data-bind="test:'testTemplate'"></span>
</div>



<script id="testTemplate" type="text/html">
<span data-bind="text:name" />
<button data-bind="click:$parent.registerClick">CLICK</button>
</script>
```

[jsfiddle reproduction here](https://jsfiddle.net/g462td77/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding context object is where `$parent`, etc. resides. You should pass `bindingContext` to `ko.renderTemplate` instead of `viewModel`:

```
ko.renderTemplate(templateId, bindingContext, {}, element, "replaceChildren");
```

I've updated your jsfiddle example with this change and couple others to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/g462td77/2/